# Partially color the name of a listcolumn

Tags: excel, vba

I want to partially color the fourth column of the table object `Sales` after the 3 to the end to `vbBlack`. Currently, the entire column name font color is white. I'm trying the following, but it gives me an error saying an object is required.

```
length = Len(Worksheets("Sales").ListObjects("Sales").ListColumns(4).Name)

Worksheets("Sales").ListObjects("Sales").ListColumns(4).Name.Characters(Start:= 4, Length:=L).Font.Color = vbBlack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListColumn.Name` is a String and a String doesn't have a `Characters` collection.

Maybe

```vb
With Worksheets("Sales").ListObjects("Sales").ListColumns(4)
    L = Len(.Name)
    .Range.Cells(1).Characters(Start:= 4, Length:=L).Font.Color = vbBlack
End With
```